# Evaluate the complex line integral $\int_C z^2dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, line-integrals

I'm having trouble understanding the concept behind complex line integrals. I think they follow the same general steps and line integrals in the real $x,y$ plane, but I'm not sure.

$$\int_C z^2dz$$
$$C: z(t)=t^2+3t$$
$$0 <t <2$$

---

My attempt:
$$dz=2t+3$$
$$z^2=t^4+6t^3+9t^2$$
$$\int_C z^2dz=\int_0^2 (t^4+6t^3+9t^2)(2t+3)dt$$
$$=\frac{1358}{3}$$

But I mainly solved this using half intuition and half guessing. I'm not confident in my understanding of this concept.

Comment: I haven't checked over the work but the procedure is correct. I find it interesting that they assign a problem about complex line integrals but the curve lays entire on the real line